# I am trying to create task scheduler but it's not reflecting to d drive

Tags: windows

command line is :

```
SchTasks /Create /SC WEEKLY /D MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI /TN “tcp.parent” /TR D:\telenet\tcp.parent\build.bat /ST 14:00
```

how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't think you are trying to create a task scheduler, but a scheduled task! :)

Comment: The typographic quotation marks look very suspicious.